# How can I query/ design for multiple relationships to the same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, relationship

Lets say I have an entity `Antenna`, which belongs to a `Site`. Each `Antenna` ***always*** has ***exactly*** 4 `Frequencies`; named `Forward`, `BackupForward`, `Reverse` and `BackupReverse`.

Now, currently I'm modelling this in my database like so;

```
Site      (id int, name string);
Antenna   (id int, site_id int, forward_frequency_id int, forward_backup_frequency_id, reverse_frequency_id, reverse_backup_frequency_id);
Frequency (id int, frequency int);
```

... but now I'm trying to retrieve all `Frequency`s which are attached to a particular `Antenna`, and it's seems to be a mess;

```
SELECT * FROM Frequency WHERE Frequency.id IN (SELECT forward_frequency FROM Antenna WHERE Antenna.id = 123) 
                           OR Frequency.id IN (SELECT forward_backup_frequency FROM Antenna WHERE Antenna.id = 123)
                           OR Frequency.id IN (SELECT reverse_frequency FROM Antenna WHERE Antenna.id = 123)
                           OR Frequency.id IN (SELECT reverse_backup_frequency FROM Antenna WHERE Antenna.id = 123);
```

What I really want to be doing is something which feels more optimal like;

```
SELECT * FROM Frequency WHERE Frequency.id IN (SELECT forward_frequency, forward_backup_frequency, reverse_frequency, reverse_backup_frequency FROM Antenna WHERE Antenna.id = 123);
```

... but SQL Server doesn't like that query construction.

Is there a more optimal way to approach this problem?

I imagine I can alleviate the problem if I define a `Antenna_Frequency` table, and map it as a many-to-many relationship, but then I loose the control over permitting ***exactly*** 4 Frequencies to each Antenna.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make an intersection table, `ANTENNA_FREQUENCY` which has three columns.  Use the two you've already thought of but add a third FK (or just a direct column) for the **frequency type**.

Make sure that the PK of the intersection table is all three columns.  This means that you will never have more than the four frequencies.  Your application logic will have to allow for the fact that a missing record in the intersection is to be treated the same way as a null FK column in your current design.

This design will ensure that you have exactly four distinct frequencies (or less, if you don't fill them out) without allowing any duplicates:

[image: ERD]

Comment: I appreciate the alternative, but is either approach "better"? I like what you've done with the PK, but like you said, this approach permits the frequencies to be left unspecified at the DB level; my current approach prevents this with NOT NULL modifiers on the relevant columns.

Comment: @Matt - There's no philosophically pure way of ensuring that a child record exists.  At least, there's nothing that can be done with declarative constraints.  You could use process to enforce your business rule.  You might consider automatically creating all of the four child records pointing at an "unknown" frequency.  This would be functionally similar to four NOT NULL columns insofar as _something_ is there, but not necessarily something _correct_.  You're going to have that problem either way.